# Jsoup Parser how to get the text from particular class

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

I need to extract the text `76` and `Houses, Apartments for Rent in` from the below markup. How do I do it using a Jsoup selector?

I tried

```
Elements elem=doc.select("h1Title >span.id");
String Pagetitle=elem.text();
```

but it didn't work.

```
<div>
  <h1 class = "h1Title">
    <span id='resultsCount'>76</span> Houses, Apartments for Rent in <span id='loc'>Koramangala</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: <div>
<h1 class = "h1Title">
<span id='resultsCount' >76</span> Houses, Apartments for Rent in <span id='loc'>Koramangala</span>
</h1>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you everything:

```
Elements elem=doc.select(".h1Title");
String pageTitle = elem.text(); //76 Houses, Apartments for Rent in Koramangala
```

If you want just the number:

```
Elements elem=doc.select(".h1Title #resultsCount");
String pageTitle = elem.text(); // 76
```

Note what you did (read more about CSS selectors if you want):

```
h1Title > span.id
element h1Title (for class, put a dot first)
this would work if you had <h1Title>
element span : ok (you have <span>)
class id! the . means class, you would have <span class="id">
for id, use # (see my example)
```

So, in short:

- foo : tag
- .foo : class
- #foo : id